# Integrate Docusign with a zoho CRM custom module

Tags: module, crm, docusignapi, zoho

I've been trying to integrate Docusign for our Zoho CRM modules.
I had researched that some similar applications doesn't support custom modules integration.

May I ask on how do you integrate Zoho CRM with a custom module I had created with Docusign? I am in need of help.

I had been linked here from the Docusign support:

[DOCUSIGN SUPPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkuJM.png)

EDIT: We need to be able to issue documents from our custom module that I had created as a starting point. I am still not quite sure if this is possible will get back here for more updates

Comment: Update: have tried adding a workflow rules and still can't integrate

Comment: If you can call DS APIs from Zoho CRM then you can integrate with DocuSign, so can you do coding in Zoho and make DS API calls?

Comment: I am not really that sure on how to code that as I am new to Docusign API which is quite confusing. I did Integrate what I can't seem to do is use Docusign for custom modules